# How to get the last folder name and file name from a path using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

how can i get the last folder name and file name  from a full path,I need a solution for this.

---

Example:

```
d:\folder1\folder2\assets\images\62f9a0f4-98b9-4dd0-8047-ed1a3cc306cf.png
```

In my case,I just need \images\62f9a0f4-98b9-4dd0-8047-ed1a3cc306cf.png from the path in Javascript.

Comment: hopefully this is your want  http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=Ru_8c7QmXhy

Comment: In what environment?  Browser, Node.js, ...

Comment: yes,its sails and coffee js,while saving the image,i just need path as i mentioned to store in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```js
var str = "d:\\folder1\\folder2\\assets\\images\\62f9a0f4-98b9-4dd0-8047-ed1a3cc306cf.png";
var ret = str.split("\\").reduce((p,c,i,arr) => {if(i >= arr.length - 2){return (p?("\\"+p+"\\"):"")+c}});
console.log(ret);
```

Comment: It will give result like this images\62f9a0f4-98b9-4dd0-8047-ed1a3cc306cf.png but i need \ before image

Comment: @TejasJain I've changed it to do that.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help.

Answer (score 1):

Not the ideal solution, but gets the work done. I had to escape the `\` while creating the string

```
var arr = "d:\\folder1\\folder2\\assets\\images\\62f9a0f4-98b9-4dd0-8047-ed1a3cc306cf.png".split("\\");

    var length = arr.length, path = "\\" + arr[length-2] + "\\" + arr[length-1];

    console.log(path);
```

Comment: It will give result like this images\62f9a0f4-98b9-4dd0-8047-ed1a3cc306cf.png but i need \ before image

Comment: You can just prepend that to the string. I will update the answer, but that is very trivial.

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
var indxend = url.lastIndexOf('/')-1
var folderName =url.substring(0,indxend).substring(url.substring(0,indxend).lastIndexOf('/')+1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a go:

```js
var path = 'd:\\folder1\\folder2\\assets\\images\\62f9a0f4-98b9-4dd0-8047-ed1a3cc306cf.png';
var parts = path.split('\\');

var file = parts.pop();
var fileAndPar = parts.pop() + '\\' + file;

console.log(fileAndPar);
```